# How to adjust edge description for automata and other tiny questions

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, automata

I am drawing an automaton using tikz but unfortunately I encountered some problems. So far it looks like this:
[image]
.

What I dislike is that

-two of the transition descriptions are two close together (I'd prefer it if (0,0,1) would be on the other side of the transition from q_0 to q_X)

-q_0 is supposed to be an accepting state but one cannot see this

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\newcommand{\tvect}[3]{%
    \ensuremath{\Bigl(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)}} %(für kleinere Matrix)

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
    semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=blue!60,draw=none,text=white]
    
    \node[state,initial,accepting] (0)          {$q_0$};
    \node[state]         (X) [below right of=0] {$q_X$};
    \node[state]         (1) [above right of=X] {$q_1$};
    
    \path 
    (0) edge [loop above]   node {\tvect{0}{1}{1}} (0)
        edge [bend left]    node {\tvect{1}{1}{0}} (1) 
        edge                node {\tvect{0}{0}{1}} (X)
    (1) edge                node {$\tvect{\square}{0}{1}$} (0)
        edge                node {\tvect{1}{0}{1}} (X)
    ;
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to adjust your node positions with `[left]` or `[right]`, and even with something like `[pos=0.6]`?

Comment: No; I don't know these commands; how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\newcommand{\tvect}[3]{%
    \ensuremath{\Bigl(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)}} %(für kleinere Matrix)

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
    semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=blue!60,draw=none,text=white]
    
    \node[state,initial,accepting] (0)          {$q_0$};
    \node[state]         (X) [below right of=0] {$q_X$};
    \node[state]         (1) [above right of=X] {$q_1$};
    
    \path 
    (0) edge [loop above]   node {\tvect{0}{1}{1}} (0)
        edge [bend left=50]    node {\tvect{1}{1}{0}} (1) 
        edge                node[left=3pt,pos=0.7] {\tvect{0}{0}{1}} (X)
    (1) edge                node[above] {$\tvect{\square}{0}{1}$} (0)
        edge                node[right=3pt,pos=0.7] {\tvect{1}{0}{1}} (X)
    ;
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Automaton]

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different positioning of edge labels (quotes), with use `positioning` and `quotes` libraries:

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\newcommand\psm[1]{$\begin{psmallmatrix}#1\end{psmallmatrix}$}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
     node distance = 15mm,
every state/.style = {fill=blue!60,text=white, 
                      minimum size=2em, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt},
                > = Stealth,
every edge/.style = {draw, ->}
                        ]
% state nodes
\node (q0) [state, accepting]  {$q_0$};
\node (qx) [state, below right=of q0]   {$q_X$};
\node (q1) [state, above right=of qx]   {$q_1$};
% connections
\path
    (q0)    edge [loop above, "\psm{0\\1\\1}"]  (q0)
            edge [bend  left, "\psm{1\\1\\0}"]  (q1)
    (q1)    edge ["\psm{\square\\0\\1}"]        (q0)
    (q0)    edge ["\psm{0\\0\\1}" ']            (qx)
    (q1)    edge ["\psm{0\\0\\1}"]              (qx);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Corrected `q0` state: it seems that it should only accepting`and not`initial`and`accepting`, so option` initial` is now deleted.

*Note*: `accepting` state differ from `initial` only in absence input arrow with label `start`. Both have double line shape border.